# Install program with different run name

Tags: command-line, apt, alias, fortran

I recently installed gfortran with `apt-get install gfortran`, but it turned out to be the latest version 4.9, which is not compatible with software that demanded gfortran in the first place. So I removed it and tried `apt-get install gfortran-4.8`. The problem is that now it can be run with `gfortran-4.8` (obviously) instead of `gfortran` which is expected by the other software.

Can I make it run with `gfortran` command?

edit:

I read about aliases and tried setting up `~/.bash_aliases` containing

```
alias gfortran='gfortran-4.8'
```

but with no effect.

Comment: What kind of build system does that software use? All the sensible ones let you configure things like compiler names/paths through command line options or environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using something later than Trusty. This isn't a problem in Trusty as gfortran is still at 4.8.

Assuming a downgrade isn't a real solution, I'll just show you how Trusty has things laid out. You might want to check it's similar in whatever you're running to make sure my conclusions are sound:

```
$ dpkg -S $(which gfortran) $(which gfortran-4.8)
gfortran: /usr/bin/gfortran
gfortran-4.8: /usr/bin/gfortran-4.8

$ file /usr/bin/gfortran
/usr/bin/gfortran: symbolic link to `gfortran-4.8'
```

So basically here, the `gfortran` command is just redirecting to `/usr/bin/gfortran-4.8`. I expect in your version it's redirecting to `/usr/bin/gfortran-4.9`.

We can override packaged path binaries without touching them. I suggest (and this may undermine things that use `gfortran` so be careful) we create a new symlink in `/usr/local/bin` (note the `local`). When you call `gfortran`, the system will find the `/usr/local/bin/gfortran` version first. Note that anything calling `/usr/bin/gfortran` explicitly will still get the 4.9 version.

Anyway, creating the symlink is easy:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran-4.8 /usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

This has the pleasant side-effect that you can leave your packages in place, fulfilling whatever dependencies you might need to fulfil. And upgrades to the `gfortran` package won't nuke our changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a symbolic link (or a "shortcut") for `gfortran-4.8` and name the shortcut `gfortran`.

First, find out where `gfortran-4.8` is actually located. You do that by running the command `which gfortran-4.8`. Let's say you get an output like this:

```
/usr/bin/gfortran-4.8
```

What you would do is execute the following command to create the shortcut:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gfortran-4.8 /usr/bin/gfortran
```

Now you (and other programs that were looking for it) should be able to run the program using `gfortran`.